# Web Projects gets auto check out on build

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I am using VS2008 with TFS 2008 and I have a web application project which gets auto check out on build.How can this be avoided? I dont want to change my Source Control changes which are auto check out on edit. When I check in the file it says file are idential, no changes...Any pointers

Answer (score 0):

Check out build log on TFS and see if any of the source files get checked out (perhaps they're being edited) during the build.

Just trigger the build manually (in your team explorer), double click on it when it's done and see the .txt log.